# 2D slice type conversion in go

Tags: go, casting

I was constrained to define a particular type for `[]string` because I implemented a custom yaml parser for the strSlice type.

Now I need to cast `[]strSlice` back into `[][]string` but the go compiler 1.7.1 reject it as an error.

```
type strSlice []string
var x1 []strSlice
var x2 [][]string
...
x2 = [][]string(x1)
```

How can I perform the cast operation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a named type of a string slice.  You need to convert each entry in  `x1` back to a `[]string` first:

```
type strSlice []string
var x1 []strSlice
var x2 [][]string
...
for _, s := range x1 {
    x2 = append(x2, []string(s))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/5iJT2Hsv1R

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this in one shot, because each of the indexes in `x1` are a `strSlice` type, and need to be converted to a `[]string` type to be stored in `x2`.  Go doesn't let you do this in a single operation because the developers didn't want to hide O(n) operations in syntactical sugar.